# How to highlight matches in the results of a search

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to let user search and that works fine but now I want that the characters of searching put which are equal of the result been Fontweight bold. But struggling with that .
Heres my code

```
class Openmyprofil extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;

  const Openmyprofil({Key key, this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenmyprofilState createState() => _OpenmyprofilState();
}

class _OpenmyprofilState extends State<Openmyprofil> {
  List _allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];

  Future resultsLoaded;
  bool nosuerfound = false;
  var titles;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.searchinginput.addListener(_onsearchChanged);
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    resultsLoaded = getusers();
  }

  _onsearchChanged() {
    print(_resultsList);
    print(_allResults);
    print(searchResults);
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = false;
    });
    searchResults();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchinginput.removeListener(_onsearchChanged());
    super.dispose();
  }

  searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        titles = tripsnapshot;
        var title = DatbaseService.instance
            .userDataFromSnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .username
            .toLowerCase();
        if (title.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
          print(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('meinprofilsettings').get();
    setState(() {
      _allResults = qn.docs;
    });
    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);

    if (nosuerfound == true) {
      return Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _resultsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    DatbaseService.instance.createorGetConversation(
                        user.uid, _resultsList[index].id,
                        (String _conversationID) {
                      NavigationService.instance.navigateToRoute(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return MeineBeitraege(
                              _conversationID,
                              _resultsList[index].id,
                              _resultsList[index].data()['username'],
                              _resultsList[index].data()['url'],
                              _resultsList[index].data()['email']);
                        }),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                  leading: Container(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                      child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: _resultsList[index].data()['url'] != null &&
                                  _resultsList[index].data()['url'] !=
                                      "profilepictureer"
                              ? Image.network(
                                  _resultsList[index].data()['url'],
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                )
                              : Image.asset(
                                  'assets/profilepictureer.png') // Your widget is here when image is no available.
                          ),
                    ),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(_resultsList[index].data()['username'],
                      style: widget.searchinginput.text.contains(
                                  _resultsList[index].data()['username']) ||
                              widget.searchinginput.text.contains(
                                  _resultsList[index].data()['username'])
                          ? TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                          : null),
                  subtitle: Text(_resultsList[index].data()['email']),
                );
              }));
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
        child: Container(
            child: Text(
          "No user found",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        )),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

So widget.searchinginput is my TextEditingController and I what I want is like if user type Mi
and I have a name Mike in _resultlist then Mi of Mike should be bold and then user typed Mik
,Mik in resultless should be bold hope anyone can help .
If you need more information please leave a comment

Comment: It is a bit complex, but to make some parts bold and others not, you need to use Text.rich. I recommend using RegExp to find the parts that should be bold. Could you please format the code better so that I can help you?

Comment: I edit it please check

Comment: Ok. I am trying to make the code work before I send it. Just a moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you need to highlight the text that is being searched by applying a custom style to it, in the case you asked for is changing the font weight to bold.

To make some parts of the text different than others you need to use a `Text.rich` widget, and to find which parts needs to be highlighted I recommend using `RegExp`.

I made a widget that can help you achieve what you asked for:

```dart
class HighlightedMatchesText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String searchString;
  final String content;

  const HighlightedMatchesText({
    Key? key,
    required this.searchString,
    required this.content,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final matches = searchString.isEmpty
        ? <RegExpMatch>[]
        : RegExp(searchString).allMatches(content).toList();
    final parts = <InlineSpan>[];
    if (matches.isEmpty) {
      parts.add(TextSpan(text: content));
    } else {
      var i = 0;
      var matchIndex = 0;
      while (true) {
        // if we moved through all matches, we can stop, and the rest
        // of the text is not going to be bold
        if (matchIndex >= matches.length) {
          final end = content.substring(matches.last.end);
          if (end.isNotEmpty) {
            parts.add(TextSpan(text: content.substring(matches.last.end)));
          }
          break;
        }
        final match = matches[matchIndex];
        // if the start of the current match is after the current index
        // then this parts should not be bold until the start of the match
        if (match.start > i) {
          final slice = content.substring(i, match.start);
          parts.add(TextSpan(text: slice));
          i = match.start;
          continue;
        }
        // this part here is where it gets bold
        final slice = content.substring(match.start, match.end);
        parts.add(TextSpan(
          text: slice,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ));
        matchIndex += 1;
        i = match.end;
      }
    }

    return Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: parts,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use it instead of the current `Text` widget. The `searchString` is what you are searching for, and the `content` is the content to be displayed, in your case I believe it is the username.

Use it like this:

```dart
HighlightedMatchesText(
  searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
  content: _resultsList[index].data()['username'],
);
```

Comment: I see one problem im using   final TextEditingController searchinginput;

Comment: Will it be ok if I load my howle page so maybe you can understand a bit better because your code is in my opinion really complex ?

Comment: I edited and added an example on how you would use it.

Comment: im sorry I dont understand it . It says undefined name search string ,undefined name content ,I will update my code so you can understand a bit better .

Comment: Ok please check out :)

Comment: Here is the widget being used: https://dartpad.dev/65df98cde8904110717483fe50b64c97?null_safety=true

Comment: Just replace the `title:` attribute value with what I provided. Instead of using Text...

Comment: I add it directly after title like this title:   final matches = searchString.isEmpty..... it says except an identifier

Comment: Just the component, on my second code block, replace what you have in `title` with that...

Comment: ok got it is a own class why you dont say that at the beginning hahah thank you men have a nice day

Comment: OK i test it but found one issue how to take care about to lowercase to uppercase ? Like if user tap Sin and  I have to names Sina and sina how can I make both of them the first 3 letters font weight bold and not just Sin of Sin?

Comment: make the `RegExp`case insensitve `RegExp(searchString, caseSensitive: false)`

Comment: Ok one last  How can I add some style for text?

Comment: after `children: parts,` you can add a normal `TextStyle` in the attribute named `style`, but to be cleaner, make it an attribute of the widget

Comment: ok got it but theres another problem please check this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149018/how-can-i-add-3-widgets-in-one You will probably the only one how understand this problem if not please leave a comment