# How can I add 3 widgets in one?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to show 3 widgets with 3 different on tap functions, but it is not working.
So what I want is the whole widget split in 3 different widgets so I can call widget 1 widget 2 or widget 3. But this is not working and I don't know why exactly.
I have this videos collection where users videos are uploaded with 3 hashtags and what I want is that the user can search for one hashtag no matter which one, but it always shows all 3 hashtags instead of the one which the user searched for. And that is what I mean with 3 different widgets.

Here is my code:

```
class Openalldocs extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;
  static const route = '/openalldocs';

  const Openalldocs({Key key, this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenalldocsState createState() => _OpenalldocsState();
}

class _OpenalldocsState extends State<Openalldocs> {
  List _allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];
  Future resultsLoaded;
  bool nosuerfound = false;
  String searchresult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.searchinginput.addListener(_onsearchChanged);
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchinginput.removeListener(_onsearchChanged());

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    widget.searchinginput.text;
    resultsLoaded = getusers();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  _onsearchChanged() {
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = false;
    });
    searchResults();
  }

  searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        var title = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag1
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        var title2 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag3
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        var title3 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag2
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        if (title.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title2.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title3.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('videos').get();
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _allResults = qn.docs;
    });
    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    if (nosuerfound == true) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _resultsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          HighlightedMatchesText(
                            searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                            content: _resultsList[index].data()['hashtag1'],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 3),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          HighlightedMatchesText(
                            searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                            content: _resultsList[index].data()['hashtag2'],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          HighlightedMatchesText(
                            searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                            content: _resultsList[index].data()['hashtag3'],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 3),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
              ]);
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: Text(
            "No Hashtag found",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          )),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you see that all your onTap handlers are empty? To do what you are asking, it is better to make a for loop inside the children array, and make the onTap function relative to the value you want.

Comment: ok and how can I do this ?

Comment: I added an answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: I changed it because it was missing a return before the InkWell

Answer (score 1):

Your `onTap` handlers are empty, so nothing will happen actually when tapping.

To achieve what you are trying to, it is better to instead of creating widgets one by one in the Column children, create a for loop, and make the onTap and everything relative to it.

Here is how to achieve it (I took only a subsection of the code, the `Column` part):

```dart
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    // the AMOUNT is how many hashtags you want to show
    for (var i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i += 1) ...[
      // the SizedBox will only exist between the elements in the list
      // as before
      if (i != 0) SizedBox(height: 6),
      // create a builder to allow declaring a variable 
      Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          // declare the hashtag variable
          final hashtag = 'hashtag$i';

          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // do something with the hashtag stored in the variable
              // this will make it relative to the element in the list
            },
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // why is there a Column inside another with only one child?
                // I would recommend to remove it
                Column(
                  children: [
                    HighlightedMatchesText(
                      searchString: widget.searchinginput.text,
                      // notice how I am using the hashtag variable here
                      // instead of a constant? ('hashtag1'), by the way
                      // the for loop will make the hashtag start at 0
                      // you can change it by increment in the declaration
                      // `final hashtag = 'hashtag${i+1}'`, if you want
                      // the existing behavior
                      content: _resultsList[index].data()[hashtag],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // what is this? if it is to add more space between the items
                // in the list, I recommend removing it from here, and add it
                // to the first `SizedBox` in the for loop
                // in case you do that, the Column that this widget belong
                // would also only now contain one widget, so, there is no
                // need to have it
                SizedBox(height: 3),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        },
      );
    ],
  ],
);
```

I added a lot of comments, I hope they help you to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: It says string most not be null

Comment: It is probably because I start the hashtags at 0. See comment on how to solve it.

Comment: Ok there are weird problems but lets do step for step . First let me explain a bit. The all results list is a list of all hashtags and I think theres something wrong .I will update picture how it looks now. it looks same as before just with a lot of space but still the same 3 hashtags in one bucket  . So the all result list is printing  when user tap nothing in . And then user can only pick one hashtag thats inside all result if you look at my search result method .Now  Im getting an error when tapping letters I dont know why but on some letter it works correctly and it only show one hashtag

Comment: And then I gettt an error that says invalid string must not be null. So I think your idea is great was exactly I was also thinking but you code filter not correctly or maybe on the wrong position ? I dont know maybe you know . And also is dont show me sometime not one hashtag of buclet even the other hashtag of that bucket not contains the letters im really confused I trie to figure out a template

Comment: So maybe lets first figure out why it shows right at the beginning this 3 hashtags like the photo that I updated because I think theres the problem . I should say these hashtags that you see are each 3 in from one video so each I will call it bucket are the hashtags of one video

Comment: I actually don't know anything about firestore, I can only help you with Flutter and layout. You should debug to check what is coming in the results and see if it is what you expect.